# MySQL: How to delete rows from the set?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a request of translation:
(table structure:

1. line_id
2. lang ("en" or "ru")
3. text

so, in the table it looks like:

```
5 | en | Test
6 | en | Hello!
7 | en | Another words
6 | ru | Привет!
```

and all translations are in the same table with key line_id, that is independent from the language)

```
SELECT txt.line_id, txt.text AS o, ru.text AS t 
  FROM text AS txt, text AS ru 
 WHERE txt.line_id = ru.line_id 
   AND txt.lang = 'en';
```

it will return such array

```
> [5] => Array ( [line_id] => 5 [o] => Test [t] => Test 
> [6] => Array ( [line_id] => 6 [o] => Hello! [t] => Hello! ) 
> [7] => Array ( [line_id] => 6 [o] => Hello! [t] => Привет! )
```

o - is original text, t - translation.

How to delete from set #6 row, because we have translation in the next row. GROUP BY will kill #7 and save #6 row.

the best result would be:

```
> [5] => Array ( [line_id] => 5 [o] => Test [t] => ) 
> [6] => Array ( [line_id] => 6 [o] => Hello! [t] => Привет! )
```

without [o] => Hello! [t] => Hello!

Comment: delete from table t where line_id = 6 and lang = "en" ?

Comment: no. in the table: 1 ROW: line_id=6, lang='en', text='Hello!'; 2 ROW: line_id=6, lang='ru', text='Привет!'

Comment: could you provide what you have in table? take 2 id and provide some example

Comment: I think the problem is there are texts in the table, either in lang=en or in lang=en and lang=ru, and now the statement has to select all lang=ru texts and if those don't exist lang=en text for the translation. Something like an array-merge.

Comment: so u want to delete `2 | en | Hello` record, as it is available in lang `ru`... Correct? **NOW as per new update it is `6 | en | Hello!`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing you probably need:

```
SELECT txt.line_id, 
         txt.text AS o, 
         COALESCE (ru.text,'UNTRANSLATED') AS t 
FROM 
  text AS txt
LEFT JOIN 
  text AS ru 
ON txt.line_id=ru.line_id AND ru.lang='ru'
WHERE txt.lang='en'
```

Answer (score 0):

exclude the original language from the translation table

```
SELECT txt.line_id, txt.text AS o, ru.text AS t 
FROM text AS txt, text AS ru 
WHERE txt.line_id=ru.line_id 
   AND txt.lang='en' 
   AND ru.lang!='en'
```

new version for new description

```
SELECT txt.line_id, ru.lang, ru.text AS t 
FROM text AS txt, text AS ru 
WHERE txt.line_id=ru.line_id 
   AND txt.lang='en'
ORDER BY text.lang, txt.line_id
```

Comment: That would kill the english fallback.

Comment: yes, but i'm need to show not only rows with translations... so, i added the best result in the description, that i want to have.

Comment: changed the answer to the new description

Answer (score 0):

How about sort by lang desc (so ru is on top) and then group by line_id?

Comment: i wrote "ORDER BY line_id ASC, t DESC" to sort the rows, but the "GROUP BY" must go **before** ORDER BY, i think :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to list translated rows and original rows without translation, you must face the lack of support in MySql for sub queries that access the same table.

In my opinion you could divide the problem: first list original rows without translations with one SELECT; then list translations with another SELECT; in the end use a UNION.

```
-- original without translations
SELECT txt.line_id, txt.text AS o, ru.text AS t 
FROM text AS txt LEFT JOIN text AS ru 
ON(txt.line_id = ru.line_id AND txt.lang = 'en' AND ru.lang != 'en')
WHERE ru.line_id IS NULL -- ensures no translations have been found

UNION

-- only matching translations
SELECT txt.line_id, txt.text AS o, ru.text AS t
FROM text AS txt JOIN text AS ru 
ON(txt.line_id = ru.line_id AND txt.lang = 'en' AND ru.lang != 'en');
```

Best regards.